# unexpected "The connection was reset" , on page reload

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

When I accessing zf2 application,it shows "The connection was reset" on browser ! . Sometime it shows this message in bowers and sometimes it not !

[image: connection reset]

The following are my technologies, I used to build application .

- Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
- PHP Version 5.4.4
- Xampp
- Zend Framework 2

error.log contents after clearing, and restarted apache

```
[Tue Apr 09 15:33:25.956011 2013] [core:warn] [pid 9664:tid 252] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Apr 09 15:33:26.343034 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 9664:tid 252] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 09 15:33:26.388036 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9664:tid 252] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 09 15:33:26.388036 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9664:tid 252] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
[Tue Apr 09 15:33:26.388036 2013] [core:notice] [pid 9664:tid 252] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Apr 09 15:33:26.390036 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9664:tid 252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6904
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release D:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:19
[Tue Apr 09 15:33:27.640108 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6904:tid 264] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 09 15:33:27.687110 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6904:tid 264] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:36.488046 2013] [core:warn] [pid 7260:tid 252] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:42.367382 2013] [core:warn] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:42.821408 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:42.866410 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:42.866410 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:42.866410 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:42.867410 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6012
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release D:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:19
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:44.070479 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6012:tid 264] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:44.117482 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6012:tid 264] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:52.011933 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:52.481960 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:52.527963 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:52.527963 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:52.527963 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:52.528963 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9964
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release D:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:19
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:53.731032 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 9964:tid 264] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:53.783035 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9964:tid 264] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Apr 09 15:34:59.654371 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:00.219403 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:00.267406 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:00.267406 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:00.267406 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:00.268406 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9552
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release D:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:19
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:01.506477 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 9552:tid 264] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:01.553479 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9552:tid 264] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:03.754605 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:04.245633 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:04.290636 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:04.290636 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:04.290636 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Apr 09 15:35:04.291636 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4036:tid 252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9232
```

Please help !

Comment: Check Apache's logs, see if it reports errors or if it's restarting.

Comment: Apache logs? PHP logs?

Comment: @AydinHassan updated question with error.log .. I could not figure out exact issue

Comment: Do you happen to use Sphinx in that application?

Comment: It seems like a redirect loop to me.

Comment: @akond no I am not using sphinx

Comment: We had similar symptoms. In out case Apache produced core dumps, which we were able to analyze and figure out the source of the problem.